# How to find contiguous words in array

Tags: php

ok, this is driving me insane, the solution must be easy but I've hit the proverbial wall,

here it is:

```
suppose I have this Array: a, b, c, d

I want to find all the contiguous letters in the array without mixing them, such as:

a b c d
a b c
a b

b c d
b c

c d
```

I've done many tests, but for some reason I just can't get it right. Any hint would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Give us examples of some of your "many tests". What did you do so far? What's wrong?

Comment: An example of your tests would be great.

Comment: So `a c d` would give false in this case?

Comment: yes, this is meant for a search engine, in order to find wordforms

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$arr = Array('a', 'b', 'c', 'd');
for ($i = 0; $i < count($arr); $i++) {
    $s = '';
    for ($j = $i; $j < count($arr); $j++) {
        $s = $s . $arr[$j];
        if (strlen($s) > 1) {
            echo $s.' ';
        }
    }
}
```

OUTPUT:

```
ab abc abcd bc bcd cd
```